# Getting Peers into ASP.NET-MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here where I work I am trying to get the MVC framework accepted as the framework to use moving forward.

The boss is quite keen to move forward but thinks it's a huge risk to take given I'm the only one that knows the framework.

I've sent multiple emails out about training sessions, and put my hand up in many a meeting for again training sessions but no matter how many times I do it I can't seem to get a single one of these people fired up.

I've given small demos and they all ooohh and ahhh at it but when it comes time to actually [learn] something, no one bothers to get on board.

Has anyone encountered the same sort of developer malaise and managed to overcome it?

Comment: Is there another technology your peers would like to adopt?  Maybe you could start a small project with them using both.

Comment: HUH!  They can't even be bothered researching WCF or WWF.  It's like we're working for the government here and they've all retired.

Comment: Are you currently a .NET WebForms shop or some other language?

Comment: We're WebForms at present but I'm trying to change that bit by bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get people interested in a new technology / methodology or whatever it may be, is to show them advantages. They don't need to be tangible - just enough that they realise.

You need to have a few things to be able to convince people of a point:

- Show them problems that already exist within the current setup. These should be obvious and to a degree, unarguable. If you struggle to find any issues with the current way of doing things - then maybe what you have at the moment is OK after all.
- Show them the benefits of what MVC would bring to them. So easier Unit Testing, Friendly URLs (a .NET4 feature now though), more "at one with the HTML", rather than abstracted away from it with WebForms (this isn't always a benefit), etc.
- Show them its not too different. It's still the same code and ideas that they are used to.

Developers are normally a tricky bunch and they like their technology stack, whatever it may be. Prehistoric or shiny-and-new, whatever: it's their current Awesomeness.

As to how you can go about presenting this information in a format that would engage your peers is a completely different matter. Whatever - it needs to be short and sweet and leave them interested to some degree. You should find that possible to do with just a 5 minute wax-lyrical.

If you manage to mention all this and sell it well - and still your peers don't give a flying monkey about MVC (to at least the degree of curiosity), then your peers may not be "Developers", but merely "people with a day job developing", who just do what they need to and go home. (Nothing necessarily bad about this category of developer - but you'll rarely get them fired up about a new-and-shiny).

Comment: +1 Actually, that advise is the best I've heard ever.  I think the next step would be to solve a few of the WebForm issues we have and give a demo to the boss and then the flock.  But yeah, those bullet points are very good thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While not knowing the personality dynamics of your team, including your boss, he may be the one that needs to be convinced not only that it is a great idea, but also the business value that may lie in the switch itself. If he is convinced that the benefit outweighs the current value, then as a leader, he needs to at least make an effort to influence the team as a whole in that direction.

This is easier said than done, I know; however, echoing the responses above, the kind of resistance we meet with developers completely engrossed in their "technology stack", for its own sake, is typically only dealt with by either mandate or attrition.

It is a difficult situation, but not hopeless. To be honest, when I finally sat down and took a look at ASP.NET MVC, I saw how clean the concept is and have not turned back. I would hope that your peers would see how this could improve their development experience.

Comment: +1  Couldn't agree more @Tom and it's overcoming the initial resistance to learning something new.  I think when these guys leave here of a night, that that's pretty much it for most of them.  I think I'm going to need to get the Boss to [encourage] them to attend a demo session.

Answer (score 1):

As a selling point in your argument, I would convey to your boss/team that your team can use their existing skills in the .NET Framework, C#/VB.NET, css, html, etc. So learning the MVC Framework should not be that drastic for most development teams. When you make your case, you should show these short videos that can be found at [http://www.asp.net/mvc/][1]:

[link text][1]

[link text][2]

[1]: http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-8144.aspx - Why ASP.NET MVC? (3 mins.)
  [2]: http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/video-8145.aspx - Technical Overview (10 mins.)

Try to find some "LIVE" ASP.NET MVC sites to also make your point.

Comment: I've already been down this avenue.  I've downloaded the vids and made them available on our intranet.  So far none of them have been watched.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Sounds like you may be wasting your time. If people don't want to at least learn what a new technology is about, then there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

May be a good sign you need some new peers. ;)

Comment: Now, whilst not very helpful, is still very funny.  :)

Comment: While this is somewhat in jest, there is some truth to it too.  One thing that doesn't change (much) is a person's motivation to improve themselves, ie, 'sharpen their saw'.  If they don't have it, there is nothing you can do to give it to them.  I'm guessing you don't fit in with the rest of your organization in that regard, and I'd encourage you to start looking for something that's going to allow you to be happy.  Your peers here will only drag you down!

Comment: Whilst that thought has crossed my mind, and you are absolutaly right, I actually like the company I work for and would like to stay here a couple more years at least.  I'm trying to find the right argument that I can present that would encourage them to pick up the books we have here and to look at the framework.  Or the demos I've made.